# Strange characters after URL -> /#.UAfaBbTY-iE

Tags: uri

I'm not sure how it's happened, but on each page there are some characters appended to the URL, similarly to the following one:

- http://example.com/rndsite/#.UAfaBbTY-iE

They seem to be the same for each page. Anybody know what is causing this?

Comment: Sounds like a browser plugin adding something to URLs for tracking purposes. Try disabling any installed browser plugins to see if you can isolate the problem

Comment: Are you redirected there even if you directly visit: http://example.com/rndsite page?

Comment: Yes I'm re-directed there no matter what I type in, and it happens cross-browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have an AddThis widget on any of the pages?  This is a known issue with that widget.  to resolve change this portion of the snippet:

```
var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};
```

WITH

```
var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":false};
```

Comment: No problem.  I ran into this same issue before.  Nearly drove me insane.  Glad I could help.

Comment: I was having the same problem.It's not really an issue but it's very annoying! Thank you man!